# split binary data into array or classes in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I split a buffer of binary data in Node.js by a binary delimiter? For example, a socket data is sent with binary code with each field dilimited by \xb8. How can I split that into an array?

Better yet, is there some way to write a class or something that it can be loaded into? For example, each packet sends command-argument pairs delimited by \xb8. Is there anyway I can take a variable with binary data and break into multiple **Command** instances?

Comment: Are you having trouble with simply iterating over the buffer looking for \xb8?

Comment: I don't know how to do anything binary with NodeJS.

Comment: True enough. Just remember, hex isn't magic. You can just as easily loop over everything and compare it with 216 instead of 0xD8 since they are the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the [Buffers documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).

Iterate through each character in the buffer and create a new buffer whenever you encounter the specified character.

```
function splitBuffer(buf, delimiter) {
  var arr = [], p = 0;

  for (var i = 0, l = buf.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (buf[i] !== delimiter) continue;
    if (i === 0) {
      p = 1;
      continue; // skip if it's at the start of buffer
    }
    arr.push(buf.slice(p, i));
    p = i + 1;
  }

  // add final part
  if (p < l) {
    arr.push(buf.slice(p, l));
  }

  return arr;
}
```

Comment: you mean I can actually use \x(hex value here) just like a variable?

Comment: Oh sorry the syntax is 0x(hex value here).

Comment: that is soo cool. Now what if I needed 4 bytes? could I just use 0xb8bb?

Comment: @DeaDEnD I don't think that inner if will work as you want it to. Why not just change the iteration bounds instead of the if? Also, don't forget that you might get part of a packet at the end, depending on how the data is sent.

Comment: @LordZardeck That's 2 bytes, but yes :P

Comment: @LoganF.Smyth yeah, that's right. 1 hex = 4 bits. 2 hex to a byte. Thanks guys!

Comment: @LoganF.Smyth but wait a minute. I couldn't do 0xbebb since he is using 1 byte correct? (buf[i])

Comment: @LordZardeck right, that's true. If you wanted to compare 4 bytes in a buffer you'd either have to do one byte at a time or use http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.6/api/buffers.html#buffer.readUInt32LE

Answer (score 0):

> binary code with each field dilimited by \xb8. How can I split that into an array?

Using [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops) library, we can process a buffer as an iterable object:

```
import {pipe, split} from 'iter-ops';

const i = pipe(buffer, split(v => v === 0xb8));

console.log([...i]); // your arrays of data
```